# Какой знак нужен перед "не"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Есть тут у нас пара рысаков не очень быстрых, правда, но выносливых.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Есть тут у нас пара рысаков ― не очень быстрых, правда, но выносливых.***

С помощью тире обособлены однородные определения (конструкция присоединительная).

Обособление связано с **распространенностью** оборота.

Сравнить: ***У нас есть рысаки не быстрые, но выносливые.*** Здесь нет обособления: определительный оборот является смысловым центром высказывания, пауза отсутствует.